# Pack schema files in a dll to secure them from tampering

Tags: c#, xsd-validation

I have a similar problem to [C# - Validating xml file against local .xsd security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369279/c-sharp-validating-xml-file-against-local-xsd-security-issues).

but my point is not a security concern in the first place. I'm hoping to secure my schema files against a "stupid user" more than an actual attacker.

Is there a possibility to pack my xsd-files into a dll at compile time and use it from there during runtime (instead of just reading a text file from the file system)?

If it would be inside a dll the "stupid user" wouldn't be able to just edit the files by accident and for an attacker we could even go further and protect the dll with strong-naming and digital signatures.

```
internal class XmlValidator : Validator
{
    private static XmlSchemaSet _schemas;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="XmlValidator"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    internal XmlValidator()
    {
        string path;
            path = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        }
        else
        {
            path = @".\";
        }

        // Add schemas
        _schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
        _schemas.Add("http://myschema/schema1", Path.Combine(path, "Schemas", "schema-v1.0.xsd"));
        _schemas.Add("http://myschema/schema11", Path.Combine(path, "Schemas", "chema-v1.1.xsd"));

    }
```

So instead of reading them directly from the file system during initialization I would like to read them as some kind of resource.

So something similar to translation files. Created at compile time and unchangeable during runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure this is possible. I do it the same way to protect them.

First declare them as `Embedded Resource`

[image]

Use it in code

```
public void LoadXsd()
{
    string resourceName = "DefaultNamespace.specs.info.IErrorInfo.xsd";
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    XmlSchema xsd = XmlSchema.Read(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName), _XsdSchema_ValidationEventHandler);

    XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    schemaSet.Add(xsd);
}

private void _XsdSchema_ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    _Logger.Error($"XSD validation error: {e.Message}");
}
```

It would be also possible to load them all at once:

```
public void LoadAllXsdFiles()
{
    XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    var allXsdFiles = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where(r => r.EndsWith(".xsd"));
    foreach (string xsdFile in allXsdFiles)
    {
        XmlSchema xsd = XmlSchema.Read(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(xsdFile), _XsdSchema_ValidationEventHandler);
        schemaSet.Add(xsd);
    }
}
```